# Integration by parts for line integrals

Tags: integration, mathematical-physics

I asked a question on physics stack exchange a few days ago here:

https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/67181/where-can-i-find-the-full-derivation-of-helfrichs-shape-equation-for-closed-mem

and got some really good answers. The one I accepted seemed like it made sense at first glance, but at a closer look it's puzzling me. The answerer uses the properties $(i,j=u,v)$

$$ \oint f \phi_i du dv = - \oint f_i \phi du dv $$
$$ \oint f \phi_{ij} du dv = \oint f_{ij} \phi du dv $$

which seems sort of odd. He's using a line integral to denote a double integral (physicists, you know... I do it too) and I'm just very confused as to where this property came from. As far as I know, integration by parts in 2D doesn't look like that. Does the claim make any sense? Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: Are you sure the poor notation isn't in fact representing the integral over a closed surface? Although then I would doubt that in general we have global coordinates $(u,v)$. Then it's basically Stokes's Theorem (with no boundary integral). If it's really a double integral over a plane region, then you need $f$ or $\phi$ to vanish on the boundary curve.